# Adding new size for Media screen in functions.php not working

Tags: images

Hi I am trying to add new size under the large size in Media Settings, but that's not working, I have studied different articles but for sure I am missing something, please guide me on this.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:** http://prntscr.com/g2idly

```
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    add_image_size( 'featured-large', 640, 294, true ); // width, height, crop
    add_image_size( 'featured-small', 320, 147, true );

    add_image_size( 'medium-width', 480 );
    add_image_size( 'medium-height', 9999, 480 );
    add_image_size( 'medium-something', 480, 480 );

    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpshout_custom_sizes' );

    function wpshout_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
        return array_merge( $sizes, array(
            'medium-width' => __( 'Medium Width' ),
            'medium-height' => __( 'Medium Height' ),
            'medium-something' => __( 'Medium Something' ),
                ) );
    }
```

This is the code I am trying to put in and testing but nothing happening.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to this.

```
function wpshout_custom_sizes($sizes) {
  $sizes['medium-width'] = __( 'Medium Width' );
  $sizes['medium-height'] = __( 'Medium Height');
  $sizes['medium-something'] = __( 'Medium Something');
  return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpshout_custom_sizes' );
```

Comment: this is not working I have already tried